# Why my storage variable doesn't load when my functional component mounts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to save my store(array of todos) in `localStorage` when my functional component unmounts. And when my component mounts (for example when `App` refreshes), it should read that variable from `localStorage`.

But why when I refresh the app, previous data doesn't load?

This is a part of my code:

```
function App() {

    const storeContents = useSelector(state => state.todo);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        const todos = localStorage.getItem("dd");
        if(todos){
            dispatch({type: "todos/loadTodos", payload: JSON.parse(todos)})
        }
        return () => {
            localStorage.setItem("dd", JSON.stringify(storeContents));
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    },[])
.
.
```

My slice:

```
const todoSlice = createSlice({
    name: "todos",
    initialState: [],
    reducers: {
        loadTodos(state, action){
            return action.payload;
        },
.
.
```

I checked this question and used `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` but it doesn't work again: [React Redux Toolkit: How can I can store my initialState to localStorage using createSlice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67248867/react-redux-toolkit-how-can-i-can-store-my-initialstate-to-localstorage-using-c)

Link to complete code: https://github.com/arman-ebrahimi/TodosApp

Link to output: https://dapper-basbousa-c1c0e6.netlify.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The only place you update the local storage is in `App` in that `useEffect`'s clean-up function. The problem is that `App` will never be unmounted as it's your main component, and it's not rendered conditionally. When someone closes its tab or refreshes the page, you are not in React's component lifecycle anymore.

## Solution

What you can do that would simplify your code is to change `initialState` in `todoSlice` to:

```
initialState: localStorage.getItem("dd") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dd")) : []
```

Change your `useEffect` in `App.js` as below to update the `localStorage` after each change:

```
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("dd", JSON.stringify(storeContents));
}, [storeContents]);
```

Comment: Hello and Thanks for the good answer. But I have a question about updating storage! why my code is wrong? Actually `storeContents` updates after each change to store and before it unmounts, it has the newest value of the store. So after running `localStorage.setItem("dd", JSON.stringify(storeContents));` the newest value saves in storage. What is wrong here?

Comment: Hi @ArmanEbrahimi, I have added an explanation about why your attempt is not working.

Comment: Thank you for explaining @yousomar:) It was interesting for me. Does it mean that just `index.js` and `app.js` don't have an unmount method? Or the rule is this: `Only any component that is rendered conditionally, has an unmount?`

Comment: My pleasure. Yeah, it's the second case, only any component that is rendered conditionally, when this condition became falsy gets unmounted. Also, a component gets unmounted if its parent gets unmounted for the same reasons. You can visualize it in the console by visiting this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-khayyam-1r91n3?file=/src/App.js) I created.

Comment: When I say condition here, it's in a larger sense. As a component rendered as part of a list and then removed from the list is also included.